# how to match graph and messenger messages?

Tags: facebook

I am receiving messages via graph and messenger API in order to improve  user experience. Private messages are duplicated on these 2 API and I need to match duplicates.

Unfortunately user IDs and messages IDs are different between these 2 APIs. I know that I can use ID matching API to convert user IDs from one API to the other. But is there an  official way to convert a messenger message ID into a graph message ID ?

Here is an example:
messenger ID = mid.$cAALDdi6ZFO1jb_oJHVdOrTAZvk45
graph ID = m_mid.$cAALDdi6ZFO1jb_oJHVdOrTAZvk45

Obviously I can get rid the 'm_' at the beginning of graph ID to convert it into a messenger ID. Will this work for every message ? If yes please point me to the corresponding facebook doc !